# Tab bar - adding a new beam to all controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4U7p.png)

Has anyone got an example of doing something like that?
I want it to be displayed all the time while passing between other controllers. I do not want to create it again in every controller.

Comment: what does new beam mean?

Comment: Just add the view containing whatever you want to display on top of everything else.

Comment: I want it to be displayed all the time while passing between other controllers. I do not want to create it again in every controller.

Comment: then add it to the tabbarcontroller's view.

Comment: Just how can I do it? I can not add in the "TabBarController"

Comment: What kind of your beam is? is it UIView Subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Override TabBar controller's view did load, to create your beamView:

```
let beamViewHeight:CGFloat = 60

let beamView = UIView()
beamView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
beamView.backgroundColor = .black
self.view.addSubview(beamView)
```

add constraint to align it bottom, top of the tab bar:

```
let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: beamView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tabBar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: beamView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: beamView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: beamView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: beamViewHeight)

view.addConstraints([bottom, leading, trailing, height])
```

it look's like this:
[image]